# CAST function when dividing COUNT columns

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, count, decimal

Basically I've divided one count column by another count column to give me a new column called `Conversion Rate`. The problem is when using a CAST function to show 2 decimal places, they appear as 0.00 when they shouldn't be, they should be something like 0.36, 0.04, 0.56 etc. How do I get it to show the correct decimals?

Here is the code I've used:

```
CAST (((COUNT (CASE runtime WHEN '1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))/(COUNT (*))) AS DECIMAL (10,2))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing this?

```
select cast(avg(case when runtime = '1' then 1.0 else 0 end) as decimal(10, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly. Why is it that code worked but my previous one would not?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is wrong. See this [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a26ca/5)

This is what i tried:

```
 COUNT(CASE WHEN runtime = "1" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt1, COUNT(*) AS Cnt2, 
        CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN runtime = "1" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Result
```